# SQL data from table except values from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables:

- `Users` with following columns: `user_id, personal_number, request_type`
- `request_in_day` with following columns: `request_id, personal_number, date`

How do I select all values from `Users` except ones with request in xxx day from `request_in_day` table. (In `date` column from `request_in_day` I store the date for when a request was made for every user, `personal_number` is unique identifier)

Comment: Please edit your post to include some sample data (both tables) and the expected output

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Thank you guys. Below it the corect answer for What i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thsi gets all users who do not have a request on a specific date:

```
select U1.*
from Users U1
where not exists (select 1 
                  from request_in_day R2 
                  where R2.personal_number = U1.personal_number
                  and R2.date = 'xxx date'
                 )
```

Comment: Thank you JohnHC, thianis What i wanted.